# Trying to find unique records in a table that don't have a negating record

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with a whole bunch of records.

table looks like this (simplified):

```
ID       DoID          DoQty          DoType          DoValue
1        17            1              Door            15
2        17            -1             Door            -15
3        18            1              Window          75
4        19            1              Bed             125
5        19            1              Bed             134
```

so this is what I'd like to pull

```
ID    DoId          DoQty          DoType         DoValue
3      18            1              WIndows        75
4      19            1              Bed            125
5      19            1              Bed            134
```

I don't need DoID=17 because it has a 2nd line where DoQty is -1. SO that overall DoQty = 0. I only need records where there isn't a DoQty=-1. The problem here is that I do not want to group by DoID I want to be able to see the whole record line (no group by)

EDIT:

Unfortunately I might not have explained my question correctly. Basically, if I run the following query, i get the correct counts, however my goal is to get the details of each line.

```
SELECT t.DoID, 
'Available' = Sum(t.DoQty)
From t
GROUP BY t.DoID
```

This gives me grouped results from which I can't do anything with.

Comment: Your explanation doesn't match the results you present.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I updated the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use conditional aggregation here:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT DoID
    FROM yourTable
    GROUP BY DoID
    HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN DoQty < 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0
)

SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE DoID IN (SELECT DoID FROM cte);
```

This would return every `DoID` whose group of records does *not* have any `DoQty` values which are negative.

Answer (score 1):

As i understand you dont what to record where has any negative DoQty in any row. If it is correct, a possible solution is below,

```
SELECT t1.ID, t1.DoID, t1.DoQty, t1.DoType, t1.DoValue
FROM table t1
LEFT JOIN table t2 ON t2.DoQty < 0 AND t1.DoID = t2.DoID
WHERE t2.DoID IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
select t.*
from t
where not exists (select 1 from t t2 where t2.doid = t.doid and t2.doqty = - t.doqty);
```

This filters out rows where the "negative" value exists.

Answer (score 0):

> What I'm trying to do here is only pull up DoID's that don't have have a DoQty>0

Try this...

```
SELECT DoID
FROM table tbl
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
   SELECT DoID FROM table WHERE DoQty <= 0 AND DoID = tbl.DoID
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below:

With Agg AS
(
select DOID,sum(DoQty) as Qty from TableName
group by DOID having sum(DoQty)>0
)
select T.* from TableName T Inner Join Agg A
on T.DOID=A.DOID;

Answer (score 0):

You seems want :

```
SELECT *, SUM(t.DoQty) OVER (PARTITION BY t.DoID) as Available
From t;
```